# Least ordinal $\beta$ such that it is provable that $2^{\aleph_0} \leq \aleph_{\aleph_\beta}$

Tags: logic, set-theory

What is the east ordinal $\beta$ such that it is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $2^{\aleph_0} \leq \aleph_{\aleph_\beta}$?

Comment: It's provable in ZFC that there is a unique ordinal $\beta$ such that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\beta.$ Clearly, that $\beta$ is the answer to your question. If you make the question more precise, to rule out "trick answers" like that, then I'm afraid the answer is that there is no such $\beta,$ the continuum can be "arbitrarily large".

Comment: @Arthur It need not be strictly monotonic, $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$ is quite possible. On the other hand, there is Konig's cofinality theorem, which rules out e.g. $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\omega,$ and there are some restrictions at limit cardinals.

Comment: Thanks @bof - I'll make the question more precise

Comment: @bof - your newest comment may make my reformulation obsolete...

Comment: Note that $\aleph_{\aleph_\beta}$ does not immediately make sense -- the subscript should be an _ordinal_, not a cardinal. You could write $\leq \aleph_{\omega_\beta}$, but it's not clear how that yields a more answerable question that $\leq\aleph_\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this question is that we can't really prove things about *individual ordinals* -- they exist only inside the theory, not at the metalevel where we prove things. The best we can do is to prove things about *formulas that define an ordinal* -- so we *can* speak at the metalevel about the set of formulas $\phi$ such that ZFC proves
$$ (\exists! \beta: \phi(\beta)) \land (\forall\beta:\phi(\beta) \to \beta\in\mathbf{ON} \land 2^{\aleph_0} \le \aleph_\beta) $$
But it is not clear, at least not *a priori* that there is any workable concept of "least" that would allow us to ask about the $\phi$ that produces the *least* ordinal.

It might easily be that there are formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ that both provably pick out ordinals with your property, but where it is not provable that the ordinal picked out by one is smaller than the other, or vice versa.